# SQL Query- Partition into groups & calculate max- min value

Tags: sql, oracle

Need your help with a SQL query in Oracle db. I have data that I want to partition into groups when event = "Start". E.g. Row 1-6 is a group, row 7-9 is a group. I want to ignore rows with event = "Ignore". Finally I want to calculate max(Value)-min(Value) for these groups. I dont have any way to group the data.

Can this be achieved? Is it possible to use partition by Event = start. Same data is below:

```
Row       Event    Value    Required Result is max-min of value
1           Start      10          
2           A          11          
3           B          12          
4           C          13          
5           D          14          
6           E          15           5
--------------------------------------------
7           Start      16          
8           A          18          
9           B          20           4
--------------------------------------------
10          Start      27          
11          A          30          
12          B          33          
13          C          34           7
--------------------------------------------
14          Ignore     35          
--------------------------------------------
15          Ignore     36          
--------------------------------------------
16          Start      33          
17          A          34          
18          B          35          
19          C          36          
20          D          37          
21          E          38           5
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in SQL.

The following query first finds the group that a row is in, by finding the largest start before the row id.  This version uses a correlated subquery for this calculation.

It then does the grouping on the id and does the calculation.

```
select groupid, max(value) - min(value)
from (select t.*,
             (select max(row) from t t2 where t2.row < t.row and t2.event = start
             ) as groupid
      from t
     ) t
where event <> 'IGNORE'
```